# How to delete a hardlink?

Tags: windows-10, python, hardlink

***Note: I am no good in superuser or system administration. So I don't even know whether the statement of Title is correct or not.***

So, I had to use python2 for a particular project but my Windows system wasn't recognizing python2 even though I installed it and put the correct environment variables.

So, after a bit of google search, I followed this website https://samsclass.info/124/proj14/python2.7-win.htm and executed this

```
mklink /H python.exe c:\python27\python.exe
```

After I was done with my work, I uninstalled python2 and installed python3.

But when I execute
`python --version` in cmd a popup opens and it shows
`python.exe - System Error. The code execution cannot proceed because python27.dll was not found`

Please help me fix this. I have been searching internet for whole day and couldn't find anything

Comment: All you should have to do is delete the "python.exe" link and then run `mklink` again and point it at the new python exe

Comment: That's what my question is. How to do that? :(. Please help me

Comment: Added an answer. Basically `where python.exe` should tell you where the link is in your path, then you can simply `del c:\path\to\python.exe`

Comment: In the future Don use hard links like you have, it’s unnecessary, you simply overcame a system variable issue by using a hammer when a drill was required

Comment: Yeah, will keep that in mind. Thanks guys for helping me out !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the folder where you put that `python.exe`, select the file and then delete it.

If you don't know where that is then from a command prompt run `where python.exe` and then `del` whatever pops up first.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fsutil` to [remove the hardlink](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc753059.aspx).

```
fsutil reparsepoint delete python.exe
```

Comment: It shows, Error:  The file or directory is not a reparse point.